# Why doesn't this if-statement short circuit?

Tags: java, short-circuiting

I'm currently fixing a bug in someone else's Java code, but I cannot explain the bug. The code in question is the following if-statement:

```
if (locked && DEBUG_ENABLED
    && owner != null 
    && (owner.equals(playerName) || subowner.equals(playerName))
    && handleCommand(playerName, message)) {
    ....
 } else {
    ....
 }
```

In which `DEBUG_ENABLED` is initialized as `private static boolean DEBUG_ENABLED = false;` and `handleCommand` functions like this:

```
public boolean handleCommand(String name, String msg) {
    if(msg.equals("Command1")) {
        ....
    } else if(msg.equals("Command2")) {
        ....
    } ....
    } else {    // No matching command
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What puzzles me is that even though `DEBUG_ENABLED` is set to false, the code still calls and executes the `handleCommand` function. I always thought this wasn't supposed to happen due to short circuiting.
The if-statement itself in total is still evaluated as false, since only the code inside the else-block in the first snippet is executed.

So, how come this if-statement is behaving like this? Is it failing to short-circuit, or do I misunderstand the principle, or is there something completely different wrong with this part of code? (Besides the missing null check for `subowner` that is, which is done outside of this part.)

Comment: It's short circuiting for me. What Java version are you on? And is there anyway that `DEBUG_ENABLED` might be `true`?

Comment: Please describe the circumstances in which you are running this and how precisely you know that it isn't short-circuiting.

Comment: It's short circuiting for me too, are you 100% sure that `DEBUG_ENABLED == false`?

Comment: The `||` means that if `subowner.equals` returns `true`, `handleCommand` must still be checked. Since there's an OR clause, if one side is false, the other side must still be checked. `DEBUG_ENABLED` makes the left side of the `||` false, but the right side can still be true.

Comment: Wow, quick responses. Uhm, we're on 1.6. As for not short circuiting, if a match is found in that `handleCommand` function, it displays some text or performs an action. Each time when tested, those actions are witnessed, as well as the actions in the else part in the first snippet. (It doesn't show any actions being executed from if the if-statement evaluated true.)

Comment: David, I assumed that the `()` around the `||` isolated it, and that the general condition is a series of `&&`. Am I mistaken in this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible that the `&&` operator fails to short-circuit. Were you using `&` perhaps? If not it means you have made some false assumptions that previous conditions before the last one were false.

Comment: That first snippet is a direct copy of the code, as is the initialization. I've checked if `DEBUG_ENABLED` is being modified or locally declared in any way anywhere else in the code, but this isn't the case. The second snippet has been modified, but just to shorten it while getting the idea across.

Comment: @user2757672 Cant you put a breakpoint in the code directly on the condition or just before and validate that every conditions evaluates to false?

Comment: I can confirm that `DEBUG_ENABLED` is false. However, your suggestion to check every condition and what happens if they are false, is interesting. Maybe that will tell me what causes this.

Comment: @user2757672, If one of the condition evaluates to false before the last condition and the operator doesnt short-circuit, there's something very wrong with the interpreter. Test is yourself, `if (false && true && someFunction()) {}`